# Persitent .inspect on page Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, persistent, inspect

I'm learning Ruby On rails.
Actually all my articles works correctly (CRUD), but i still have my posts.inspect on my page. 
However i deleted this, but still continues to be displayed.

I checked all my files, i don't have "puts posts.inspect".
Why it still displayed ?

Check screen
Thanks for you help !

[image: persistent inspect]

Answer (score 1):

I thought you were using `<%= %>` (equal sign) instead of `<% %>` (no equal sign) in your `:each` method in your views something like this:

```
<%= @articles.each %>
# ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Oh nice ! Thank you very much ! <%= is like inspect ?

Comment: @LudovicWEBER: no, it's like puts.

Comment: in erb its not puts, its output to buffer `<% concat "something" %>` (see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat)

Comment: @FrederikSpang: of course, it's not puts, it's "like puts", conceptually.